# Javascript/NodeJS: Best way to find an specific object by id inside an array/collection of objects

Tags: javascript, loops, node.js

**Overview**

*So I have pulled out a document from my database. Inside is a nested collection of objects. Each of the objects inside this nested collection has an '_id' attribute. I want to find one on these objects specifically by its '_id' using Javascript.*

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/tNngT/

**Alternative Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/tNngT/3/

**Questions**

1. Is my example the best way of achieving this?
2. Will this block in Node.js?

Comment: The "Async Example" isn't async. I think your first example is the standard way to do it, though I'd probably return null rather than false for a not-found.

Comment: Checkout an example I made using async.js: http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/yJSjP/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you only know a specific value which is contained by one of your objects (which are held in an Array) you need to loop over the whole structure and compare those values.

As you also did right, break the iteration when you found one (`return` in your example).
So my answer to your first question would be **yes**, in terms of performance this is the right and best way.

What I don't get is the "*Async*" example. You just moved the code and changed the structure. Your code is still "blocking" since you're using a normal `for-loop` to search. If that array would be *huge*, it would block your node-app for the amount of time the loop needs to finish.

To really make it asynchronously, you would need to get rid of any `loop`. You would need to loop over the structure with a runway-timer.

```
var findById = function(collection, _id, cb){
    var coll = collection.slice( 0 ); // create a clone

    (function _loop( data ) {
        if( data._id === _id ) {
            cb.apply( null, [ data ] );
        }
        else if( coll.length ) {
            setTimeout( _loop.bind( null, coll.shift() ), 25 );
        }
    }( coll.shift() ));
};
```

And then use it like

```
findById( myCollection, 102, function( data ) {
    console.log('MATCH -> ', data);
});
```

This technique (which is a simplified example), we are creating an self-invoking anonymous function and we pass in the first array item (using `.shift()`). We do our comparison and if we found the item we are looking for, execute a callback function the caller needs to provide. If we don't have a match but the array still contains elements (check for the `.length`), we create a timeout of 25ms using `setTimeout` and call our `_loop` function again, this time with the next array item, because `.shift()` gets and removes the first entry. We repeat that until either no items are left or we found the element. Since `setTimeout` gives other tasks in the JS main thread (on a browser, the *UI thread*) the chance to do things, we don't block and screw up the whole show.

As I said, this can get optimized. For instance, we can use a `do-while` loop within the `_loop()` method and also use `Date.now()` to do things until we go over the 50ms mark for instance. If we need longer than that, create a `timeout` the same way and repeat the above described operation again (so its like, do as much operation as possible within 50ms).

Comment: I highly recommend against "making loops asynchronous" using private mechanisms of time splicing (`setTimeout`). If this is really a bottleneck it should be optimised in the database, such that the database returns a single item.

Comment: @Raynos: actually, this is a very nice pattern. Of course there are some questions you need to ask yourself before you can do it. For instance *Can my items get processed without sequence?* and *can my items gets processed without order?* If both answers are "yes" there is no problem in using run-away script timers. However, this concept might be more useful on the browser UI thread than it is on node.

Comment: What I really meant is the technique of using `setTimeout` to split up a lump of work into chunks so that other work can happen is basically [time slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Time_slice). Except your emulating it and not doing at the operating system level. What your really want is concurrency. In node this means new processes, in the browser this means web workers.

Comment: @jAndy I have done an example using async.js: http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/yJSjP/3/

Answer (score 1):

I'd pre-sort the array by each item's _id and at least implement a binary search, if not something a little more sophisticated if speed is really an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using binary search, in most cases it's faster than linear search. As jAndy said, you will still block with standard for loop, so take a look at some node asynchronous library. First that falls to my mind is async.js

Answer (score 0):

I messed around with [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) to produce this solution to my problem. I have tried make it a reusable as possible so it is not just locked down to search the '_id' attribute.

**My Solution:**

http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/yJSjP/3/

Comment: The _id makes me assume you are using mongodb, and it already has findById so why do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can generate unique strings from your _id you could hash them out with js's native object.

```
findById = (collection, _id, callback, timeout = 500, step = 10000)->
   gen = ->
      hash = {}
      for value, i in collection
         hash[value._id] = value
         unless i % step then yield i
      hash[_id]

   it = gen()
   do findIt = ->
      {done, value} = it.next()
      if done then callback value
      else 
         console.log "hashed #{(value/collection.length*100).toFixed 0}%"
         setTimeout findIt, timeout
```